# renderer returned unicode, and did not specify a charset value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-drf-renderer

I am using **Django 2.x** and **DRF**.

From my `APIView`, I want to return `pdf` or `eps` binary data file.

```
class DownloadFile(APIView):
    serializer_class = DownloadFileSerializer
    renderer_classes = (BinaryFileRenderer,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        name = serializer.validated_data.get('name')
        data = serializer.validated_data.get('imgdata')

        mimetype = None

        data, mimetype = convert_file_to_pdf_or_eps(data)

        if data and mimetype:

            response = Response(data=data, content_type=mimetype)
            ascii_name = get_ascii_name(name, "QRCode")

            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % "-".join(filename.split())

            return response
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data='Either data or mime type was missing')
```

and the **BinaryFileRenderer**

```
from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer


class BinaryFileRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    format = None
    charset = None
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data
```

This works fine for `pdf` data, but with **EPS** data, it gives error

```
renderer returned unicode, and did not specify a charset value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change from `charset = None` to `charset = 'utf-8'`